# Is it more stable to run Ubuntu 11.04, Natty Narwhal on EC2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

For example, Instagram said

**"We run Ubuntu Linux 11.04 (“Natty Narwhal”) on Amazon EC2. We’ve found previous versions of Ubuntu had all sorts of unpredictable freezing episodes on EC2 under high traffic, but Natty has been solid. "**

http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/13649370142/what-powers-instagram-hundreds-of-instances-dozens-of

Any comments? I used to thinkg 10.04 LTS is more stable in fact..

Comment: I don't think this can be answered generically.  Each person and application is going to have their own experience and it may or may not be entirely related to the Ubuntu release.  In my personal experience, 10.04 is stable on EC2.  I've had a few problems with 11.10 on my personal EC2 servers, enough to not migrate my company there just yet, but I'm still using it for other things without too much problem.  For what it's worth I found 8.04 to be super-solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Instagram Engineering forgot to turn off irqbalance? Either way, the beauty of 10.04LTS is just that -- LTS. EC2 instances may be ephemeral, but it kind of sucks upgrading the OS on your critical boxes.

LTS keeps security updates coming in when 11.04's have long since die out. We really didn't want to have to migrate services when 11.04's repos stopped receiving updates.

We have about 30 servers on AWS and most of them are 10.04.